# Событие формы

Tags: c#, wpf

Какое событие отвечает за нажатие кнопки развернуть во весь экран?

Comment: SizeChanged

Comment: оно не срабатывает при разворачивании окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отлавливаем SizeChanged и проверяем свойство WindowState:

```
   private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Max");
                }
            }
```

Только что проверил на пустом проекте